# How do I reinstall the TCP/IP protocol driver on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, tcpip

How do I reinstall the TCP/IP protocol driver on Windows 7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reinstall and reset TCP/IP (Internet protocol)

1. Click on the Start button.
2. Type Cmd in the Start Search text box.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut to run a command prompt as administrator. Allow elevation request.
4. Type `netsh int ip reset` in the command prompt shell, and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
5. Restart the computer.

Note: if you're using manually assigned TCP/IP settings, take notes as this will reset to the default 'automatically obtained'.

Comment: would you mind telling us a little more detailed about your problem?

Comment: whats the difference between doing this, and using "add new hardware" then select "windows tcp ip protocol driver" ? this work fo XP, in win7 there's no such option ...

Comment: are you looking for TCPIP.SYS? please tell us exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: well, I want to reinstall all the files and settings related to the tcp/ip driver.

Comment: funny, only this afternoon one of my windows 7 VMs crashed due to a corrupt driver (tcpip.sys), as suggested, a repair installation solved the issue.

Comment: it seems there is no other way...

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall and reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol) for Windows 7 (32 and 64):

1. Click on **Start** button.
2. Click on **Accessories**.
3. Right click on **Command Prompt** and select **Run as Administrator**.
4. Type **netsh int IP reset `C:\resetlog.txt`** in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key. Do not restart computer.
5. Type **netsh winsock reset** in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
6. Restart the computer.

You'll find a log with the changes in **`C:\resetlog.txt`**.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this a thousand times. *[How to reset TCP/IP by using the NetShell utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)* provides an EXE file to automatically do that reset for you.

Comment: it's just an automated version of "netsh int ip reset"