# Ping myself, works with ipv6 not ipv4 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ping, ipv6, ipv4

I've tried to solve the following problem with no luck and I need some proffesional help.

**The following is possible:**

- Ping all computers (that I tried) in the domain without problem.
- Ping myself with localhost which use ::1.
- Ping myself with my given ipv6 IP.
- Internet access.

**The following is not possible:**

- Noone can ping me (request timeout) with computername/ipv4/ipv6.
- I cannot ping myself with my given ipv4 IP or 127.0.0.1 (request timeout).

Tried to enable/disable TCP/IPv4. Same issue.

Turned off windows firewall. Added an inbound rule to allow icmp (just in case). Same same..

Is there someone out there that has any idea what the issue could be?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a tcp/ip issue if you cannot ping the local host.

See this answer on how to reinstall the tcp/ip protocol driver

[How do I reinstall the TCP/IP protocol driver on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/30995/how-to-reinstall-the-tcp-ip-protocol-driver-on-windows-7)

or malware has infested your hosts file.

.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it right away.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Windows 7 firewall is configured to not respond to ping requests.  You can change this behavior by following tutorials like [this by Sysprobs.com](http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7).

You can additionally verify that Network Discovery and File and Printer Sharing are turned on (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings).

Comment: Thanks for thef ast answer.Tried the guide (although firewall is turned off). Did not work:(

Comment: @user68546 - I edited the answer, try checking the additional options.

Comment: Yes..everything is turned on under "advanced sharing settings"

Answer (score 1):

The strange behaviour disappeared after I uninstalled all my VPN clients (I'm working for different customers).

One of these "clients" was probably "something more" then just a client and blocked my computer from the incoming ping calls.

After uninstallation everything works as intended. Time to start installing all these VPN clients on a virtual computer:)

Thanks everyone for your great feedback. As usual, I was the weakest link, not the hardware/software:)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting ipv4 with:

```
>netsh interface ipv4 reset
```

See [299357 - How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)