# Network connection disconnecting on application launch

Tags: networking

I have this very weird problem with my internet connection. I'm using a DHCP net connection. However, whenever I try to connect it, even if it connects, it either disconnects immediately or (most often) on the launch of any application requiring the Internet.

I've tried the following things already:

1. I have two lab cards along with the in built one and two PCI slots on my motherboard. Tried all the combinations possible but still the same result.
2. Checked my cable wire thoroughly. Doesn't seem to be a problem.
3. Ran a virus scan on my PC, found no viruses, but still opted for a clean install of windows again but nothing changed.
4. Wiped out my hard disk entirely and only kept Windows. Still same problem.
5. Referred to [Is my network card faulty?](https://superuser.com/questions/272815/is-my-network-card-faulty) for answers. Tried all of them but no improvement.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formatting since I had to post this question via the mobile site

Comment: OS?  If Windows, have you tried Safe Mode with Networking?  How about checking to see if it works via a Linux LiveCD or alike?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can a nvidia graphics card paired with an and processor on an asus motherboard cause the conflict?

Comment: @techie007 tried in windows safe mode, same problem. I don't have a Linux so is it OK if I try it on some other version of windows lest my version of windows installation CD be corrupt?

Comment: Oh and by the way, sorry not to mention, by disconnecting I mean that it shows network cable unplugged for a fraction of a  second

Comment: So does it reconnect and start working after that?  you still haven't included which version /edition of Windows you're speaking of.  You seem to indicate you have more than one Network adapter installed.  Have you tried removing and/or disabling all of them except the one you're trying to work with?

Comment: Yes... I've tried using only one adapter at a time but even that didn't work. It reconnects but takes time. And then again gets disconnected when a packet request is sent to the internet. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Might not be the PC, have you tried a different router (or whatever your plugging into to get Internet)? Or do you have other devices you can try with that connection?

Comment: I had a wireless router. But initially I started getting problems of limited connectivity. So I'd sent it for replacement thinking it's my router since it used to connect perfectly when connected directly. Started to get this problem after I formatted my PC soon after that. Formatted again and same thing again. So I thought that my PC would be the problem this time. Anyways, I'll try installing windows xp and note the results.

Comment: Okay I've tested it with multiple platforms. Used windows xp and linux live CD but nothing changed. Now, in fact, it remains unplugged and shows up only for a fraction of a second. Please help me someone.

Comment: I fit does the same under multiple operating systems, then it's a hardware fault.  If you're hooking up by wire, try a new cable (just looking at the cable isn't good enough).