# Restore default Windows registry permissions for services section

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, windows-registry, services, restore

I have a problem with registry permissions. During using my PC it freeze because of SSD controller issue. After rebooting and replacing SATA for SSD - PC was able to recognize SSD and start Windows 8.1. But looks like permissions for services in registry are screwed. A lot of services couldn't start because of `Access Denied` issue.

`Process Monitor` says that they tried to access `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\` section. My typical permissions for registry nodes in that sections are:

```
Users > Read access
Administrators > Full Control access
SYSTEM > Full Control access
CREATOR OWNER  > Full Control access
ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES  > Full Control access
```

And service specific permissions are lost. I can restore permissions manually, for example i've added `NT SERVICE\Dhcp` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcp` and then service was able to start fine. But it's hard to know what keys should be allowed to access by what services. I can use `Process Monitor` to get this data, but it might be too long. Other way - I can give `Everyone` user `Full control` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\`, but it's not secure way.

So is there any existing way to restore default permissions for services registry keys? 
I've tried to restore it with `secedit`, but it didn't help. I can also try to do Windows Repair from installation DVD, but it might take a lot of time. Maybe there is existing way for such things?

As another option i can make some simple tool that will analyze permissions from one correct computer, and then reset the same with my corrupted computer.

Windows System Restore was disabled, so i can't restore with it.

Comment: It's the kind of task I'd give to Windows aio  from tweaking. com - http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html

Comment: I'd suggest restoring your registry from a backup.

Comment: I don't have backup, so in my case it would be Windows Repair or full reinstall, that still a way, but a long one :(

Comment: This happened after some malware hijacked the services. After all traces of the software itself were gone, registry permissions were badly tweaked. I'm shocked there isn't some tool that simply resets `services` permissions. The essential Windows services and permissions are universal for a given OS release. In my situation, screwed up were Base Filtering Engine (fundamental to networking), Firewall, DHCP, and some helpers (Shared, Tcpip, Winsock2). I ended up adding `Local Service` for some, `Network Service` for others, and `Everyone` for a few where neither of the above worked.

Answer (score 1):

> A lot of services couldn't start because of Access Denied issue.

Instead of looking for a permissions rollback, I will try to give a different point of view to solve that specific problem that I quoted.

You could try to give the necessary user permissions to the entire service's registry key tree with **SetACL** application, which you could download here (it's freeware):

https://helgeklein.com/download/

---

### Steps

1. Perform a restoration point, otherwise open the command prompt (**CMD.exe**) and run these orders to make a
   backup of the service key tree:

   ```
   Reg.exe Export "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" "%Userprofile%\Desktop\CurrentControlSet.reg"
   ```

   And:

   ```
   Reg.exe Export "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services" "%Userprofile%\Desktop\ControlSet001.reg"
   ```

   (it will be saved as a registry script in the current user's desktop)
2. Run these commands to take ownership and also full acces of your current user on the registry key trees:

   ```
   "SetACL.exe" -on "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" -ot "reg" -ownr "n:%UserName%"        -rec "Yes" -actn "setowner" -silent
   "SetACL.exe" -on "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" -ot "reg" -ace  "n:%UserName%;p:full" -rec "Yes" -actn "ace"      -silent
   ```

   And:

   ```
   "SetACL.exe" -on "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services" -ot "reg" -ownr "n:%UserName%"        -rec "Yes" -actn "setowner" -silent
   "SetACL.exe" -on "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services" -ot "reg" -ace  "n:%UserName%;p:full" -rec "Yes" -actn "ace"      -silent
   ```
3. Restart the PC and see if it resulted in the expected access denial removal.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem with such approach is that each service has own user. For example `DCHP Client` services has `NT SERVICE\Dhcp` user, and a lot of services also has own users. And i dont want to manually run for each of them such update..