# Windows Networking adapter/driver problems

Tags: windows, networking

I am having a Windows networking problem. My system is a Windows Vista x86_64 System. I have a dual boot into Linux, and in Linux the networking works fine, so I know its not a Hardware/Router problem.

**Here's the problem**: Any attempts to make any connections to any computer whatsoever result in `General Failure`. If I open command prompt and type in

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

It results in `General Failure` on all four 32-byte packets before quitting.

This happened, but for some reason when I typed in `ipconfig`, it still listed the default gateway as my router.

I tried resetting the network adapter. After that happened, when I typed in `ipconfig` I had no default gateway and my IP is not a `192.168` number (my router's LAN). The same `General Failure` occured when trying to ping `127.0.0.1`.

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't ping your loopback address, that generally means there's a problem with the TCP/IP protocol stack.  Follow the steps in this answer, to try fixing the issue:

[How do I reinstall the TCP/IP protocol driver on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/30995/how-to-reinstall-the-tcp-ip-protocol-driver-on-windows-7/31002#31002)

> Reinstall and Reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol)
>
> 1. Click on Start button.
> 2. Type Cmd in the Start Search text box.
> 3. Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
> 4. Type **netsh int ip reset** in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
> 5. Restart the computer.
>
> note: if you're using manually assigned TCP/IP settings, take notes as
>   this will reset to the default 'automatically obtained'

Comment: perhaps, also **netsh winsock reset** might be of help, if the underlying problem intersects

Comment: Thanx, it worked :D