# Winsock "Permission Denied"

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am running into issues with Winsock on Windows 7. It throws the error "Permisison denied" (10013) and I am unable to fix whatever needs to be reset.

At first I thought there were issues because my version of Windows hadn't been activated. So I went ahead and re-installed and activated my version of Windows. Still not fixed.

Then I read that you should be able run "cmd" as Adminstrator and execute:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog  (resets winsock entries)
netsh int ip reset reset.log hit (resets TCP/IP stack)
```

But I still have the same issue after I restart.

Anyone have any clue what an underlying issue might be and how to help fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you doing that is causing the permission denied message? Also, check the System Event log for relevant messages. You could try 'netsh winsock reset' (without the quotes) from an elevated cmd prompt. Good luck.

Comment: See this...http://superuser.com/questions/30995/how-to-reinstall-the-tcp-ip-protocol-driver-on-windows-7

Comment: I am trying to test a VB.net application and it returns error "Permission Denied." This comes from winsock protocol error 10013. There I assume it has nothing to do with my application, but with winsock itself. I have tested it successfully on other machines, so I am most certain it is a local issue.

Comment: ps - Neither of your two options were successful.

Comment: pss - I checked the System Event log and there are no events that pop up when the error occurs. Would the error still show up if the program is handling the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've found that works:

1. Create a new user account with a different name, as follows:

   - Go to Start → Control Panel → User Accounts
   - Select "Manage other accounts"
   - "elect "Create new account"
   - Give the new account a name, e.g. "Bob2" and check the box to make it an administrator account
2. Restart the computer and login to the new account
3. Run this command from an elevated command prompt (Vista or newer):

   ```
   netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
   ```

   For Windows XP, run this command:

   ```
   netsh winsock reset
   ```
4. Restart, and the access denied error message should no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that your Winsock registry files are corrupted and need to be replaced and a way to get around this "permission denied" issue is to just replace them with new ones from  [here](http://tech-grounds.com/unidentifiednetworksolution).

Answer (score -1):

Error 10013 is most likely caused by a third-party firewall, anti-virus, or Internet security program.  Try disabling all such software to see if this is the case.  Once you have identified the offending program, it should be possible to add an exception so that you can still run both programs without interference.  If the error is intermittent, it could also be that you are trying to connect to the server too often, in violation of the server's policies (especially mail servers).